# how to abort and retry ftp download after specified time?

Tags: python, ftp, timeout, ftplib

I have a Python script which connects to a remote FTP server and downloads a file. As the server I connect to is *not* very reliable, it often happens that the transfer stalls and transfer rates become extremely low. However, no error is raised, so that my script stalls as well.

I use the `ftplib` module, with the `retrbinary` function. I would like to be able to set a timeout value after which the download aborts, and then automatically retry/restart the transfer (resuming would be nice, but that's not strictly necessary, as the files are only ~300M).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed what I need to do using the `threading` module:

```
 conn = FTP(hostname, timeout=60.)
 conn.set_pasv(True)
 conn.login()
 while True:
     localfile = open(local_filename, "wb")
     try:
         dlthread = threading.Thread(target=conn.retrbinary,
                 args=("RETR {0}".format(remote_filename), localfile.write))
         dlthread.start()
         dlthread.join(timeout=60.)
         if not dlthread.is_alive():
             break
         del dlthread
         print("download didn't complete within {timeout}s. "
                 "waiting for 10s ...".format(timeout=60))
         time.sleep(10)
         print("restarting thread")
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         raise
     except:
         pass
     localfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the timeout argument of the FTP class http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP

Comment: From the your link: "The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking operations like the connection attempt". I just tried, and the timeout argument does not seem to have any effect on `retrbinary` (only on `connect`)